# How are Azure SQL Audit blob file names generated?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I have Azure SQL Audit enabled on one of my databases. I would like to be able to automate a process whereby the contents of the file(s) for a given day are stored in a SQL table. However, to do that, I need to know the names of the blob files to process for a given day. For example in my blob folder I see the following:

[image]

In order for me to automate this process, I need to know the files that are there, and what they are named. How would I go about doing this? I will probably be using T-SQL to process these files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blob filename format: *CreationTime_FileNumberInSession.xel*

- CreationTime – time of day in UTC (hh_mm_ss_ms format)
- FileNumberInSession – a running index in case session log spans across multiple Blob files

As you can see, the file names are random as they are based on the time of day when they were created.

Audit blob files are stored in the following directories hierarchy within the "sqldbauditlogs" container (‘/’ delimiter signifies directory hierarchy):

<ServerName>/<DatabaseName>/<AuditName>/<CreationDate>/

To process all logs for a given day, simply collect all blobs in the relevant ../<CreationDate>/ hierarchy.

Thanks,

Gilad (MSFT)

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way in T-SQL to collect all blobs for a given date?

Answer (score 2):

I would do the following if you are trying to load the audits into a table.

1 - Write a power shell script get a list of the audit files in the blob storage container under the day you want to load.

2 - Use the [`sys.fn_get_audit_file`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-get-audit-file-transact-sql) table value function to load and append the file entries to your cumulative table in another database.

Here is a sample TSQL script that you might use.

```
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.fn_get_audit_file 
    ('https://sa-name.blob.core.windows.net/sqldbauditlogs/server-name/database-name/SqlDbAuditing_Audit_NoRetention/2017-11-23/12_01_02_960_0.xel',default,default);
    GO
```

3 - Use Azure Automation to schedule the PowerShell workflow on a daily timer to perform the loading.

4 - Here is a [white paper](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=829599) on the layout of the blob file.

Happy Coding.

John

The Crafty Dba